# Need to calculate difference (delta) between subsequent rows for 5 different columns

Tags: sql

Good evening everyone,

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this one. I have the following SQL Query:

```
 SELECT 
    [Vehicle_Id],
    [License_Nmbr],
    [Measurement_Date],
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM],
    MAX([Trip_Id]) AS Trip_Id,
    MAX([Distance]) AS Distance,
    FORMAT(MAX([Trip_Start_Time]), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS Trip_Start_Time, -- Modified format
    MAX([Sys_Param_Vehicle_Distance]) AS Vehicle_Distance_Odometer,
    MAX([Sys_Param_Total_Power_Consumption_KW]) AS Total_Power_Consumption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS DCDC_Energy_Consumption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consup,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Electric_Heater_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Electtri_Heater_Consuption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Trip_Motor_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Trip_Motor_Consuption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Trip_Regen_Energy_kWh]) AS Trip_Regen,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_XE_XALT_Net_Trip_Energy_kWh]) AS Net_trip_energy,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_BTMS_HV_Load_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS HV_Load_consumption,
    MAX([Sys_Param_EV_Battery_State_of_Charge_SOC]) AS SOC,
    MAX([NF_TK_AmbTemp_40_ft]) AS Temp_40,
    MAX([NF_TK_AmbTemp_FRT_60_ft]) AS Temp_60,
    
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [License_Nmbr], [Measurement_Date], [Measurement_Time_HH_MM]) AS Index_Column -- New column with an index
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        [Vehicle_Id],
        [License_Nmbr],
        CAST([Measurement_Time] AS DATE) AS Measurement_Date,
        FORMAT([Measurement_Time], 'HH:mm') AS Measurement_Time_HH_MM,
        [Trip_Id],
        [Distance],
        [Trip_Start_Time],
        [Sys_Param_Total_Power_Consumption_KW],
        [NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Electric_Heater_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Trip_Motor_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Trip_Regen_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_XE_XALT_Net_Trip_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_BTMS_HV_Load_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_TK_AmbTemp_40_ft],
        [NF_TK_AmbTemp_FRT_60_ft],
        [Sys_Param_EV_Battery_State_of_Charge_SOC],
        [Sys_Param_Vehicle_Distance]
    FROM 
        [OPM_Datawarehouse].[dbo].[ZEB_Summary]
    WHERE 
        CAST([Measurement_Time] AS DATE) >= '2023-11-01'
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    [Vehicle_Id],
    [License_Nmbr],
    [Measurement_Date],
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM]
ORDER BY
    [License_Nmbr] ASC,
    [Measurement_Date] ASC,
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM] ASC;
```

I need to add a SQL statement to add a column  that replicates the following logic that I developed with a DAX code in Power BI:

```
    DC_DC_Consumption 2 = 

var vehicle_ID = 'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[License_Nmbr]
var dateField = 'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Measurement_Date].[Date]
var timefield= 'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Measurement_Time_HH_MM]
var indexField = 'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Index_Column]
var current_value = 'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[DCDC_Energy_Consumption]

var latest_value=
IF(OR('Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[DCDC_Energy_Consumption]=0,ISBLANK('Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[DCDC_Energy_Consumption])),0,
    CALCULATE(MAX('Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[DCDC_Energy_Consumption]), FILTER('Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)',
        'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Measurement_Time_HH_MM] < timefield &&
            'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[License_Nmbr]=vehicle_ID &&
                'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Measurement_Date].[Date] = dateField &&
                    'Connect360(SQL Query Summarizing)'[Index_Column]= indexField-1
                )))

    return
current_value-latest_value
```

I also need to do the same for 6 more columns ([NF_CM0711_Electric_Heater_Energy_Consumption_kWh], [NF_CM0711_Trip_Motor_Energy_Consumption_kWh], [NF_CM0711_Trip_Regen_Energy_kWh],[NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy_kWh], [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy_kWh] and [Sys_Param_Vehicle_Distance]). Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance,

Michelle

I  tried to develop this SQL query to solve this but it didn't work because the fact that I need to include [NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh] under the GROUP BY statement is generating a rows with NULL values for DCDC_Energy_Consumption that have the same HH:MM value for the column "Measurement_Time_HH_MM":

```
 SELECT
    [Vehicle_Id],
    [License_Nmbr],
    [Measurement_Date],
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM],
    MAX([Trip_Id]) AS Trip_Id,
    MAX([Distance]) AS Distance,
    FORMAT(MAX([Trip_Start_Time]), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AS Trip_Start_Time,
    MAX([Sys_Param_Vehicle_Distance]) AS Vehicle_Distance_Odometer,
    MAX([Sys_Param_Total_Power_Consumption_KW]) AS Total_Power_Consumption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS DCDC_Energy_Consumption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consup,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Electric_Heater_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Electtri_Heater_Consuption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Trip_Motor_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS Trip_Motor_Consuption,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Trip_Regen_Energy_kWh]) AS Trip_Regen,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_XE_XALT_Net_Trip_Energy_kWh]) AS Net_trip_energy,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_BTMS_HV_Load_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) AS HV_Load_consumption,
    MAX([Sys_Param_EV_Battery_State_of_Charge_SOC]) AS SOC,
    MAX([NF_TK_AmbTemp_40_ft]) AS Temp_40,
    MAX([NF_TK_AmbTemp_FRT_60_ft]) AS Temp_60,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy,
    MAX([NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy_kWh]) AS Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [License_Nmbr], [Measurement_Date], [Measurement_Time_HH_MM]) AS Index_Column,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) = 0 OR MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]) - COALESCE(
            LAG(MAX([NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]), 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY [License_Nmbr] ORDER BY [Measurement_Date], [Measurement_Time_HH_MM]),
            0
        )
    END AS DCDC_Energy_Consumption_Difference
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        [Vehicle_Id],
        [License_Nmbr],
        CAST([Measurement_Time] AS DATE) AS Measurement_Date,
        FORMAT([Measurement_Time], 'HH:mm') AS Measurement_Time_HH_MM,
        [Trip_Id],
        [Distance],
        [Trip_Start_Time],
        [Sys_Param_Total_Power_Consumption_KW],
        [NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Electric_Heater_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Trip_Motor_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Trip_Regen_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_XE_XALT_Net_Trip_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_BTMS_HV_Load_Energy_Consumption_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_FRT_HVAC_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_CM0711_Aux_Inverter_RR_HVAC_Energy_kWh],
        [NF_TK_AmbTemp_40_ft],
        [NF_TK_AmbTemp_FRT_60_ft],
        [Sys_Param_EV_Battery_State_of_Charge_SOC],
        [Sys_Param_Vehicle_Distance]
    FROM
        [OPM_Datawarehouse].[dbo].[ZEB_Summary]
    WHERE
        CAST([Measurement_Time] AS DATE) >= '2023-11-01'
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    [Vehicle_Id],
    [License_Nmbr],
    [Measurement_Date],
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM],
    [NF_CM0711_DCDC_Energy_Consumption_kWh]
ORDER BY
    [License_Nmbr] ASC,
    [Measurement_Date] ASC,
    [Measurement_Time_HH_MM] ASC;}
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to assist you. When most people see a wall of SQL they turn away.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms used. The above SQL is product specific.